# Huzzah feather scl sda

Tags: servo

Trying to hook up an hazzah feather to a pca9685 scl sda connection and have a bno055 connected to that.The 5 volts to power the PCA is not taken from feather. I have a GPS module connected to pin 12 of feather again not powered from feather. Gps interface works fine. I see it though web page interface.
Then I hook up the PCA. the wifi chip overheats and feather is fried

Comment: you talked about +5 V, but you said nothing about grounds

Comment: The grounds are the individual power supplies

Comment: that means nothing ... how are all of the grounds connected?